# Ruby : Error while installing JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install and get running [Rails Starter kit](https://github.com/starterkits/rails4-starterkit). On running `bundle install`, I get the following :
`Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.3`

So I have changed [this line](https://github.com/starterkits/rails4-starterkit/blob/master/Gemfile#L2) to `ruby '2.3.0'` and try again the command : [see here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b2f3ee739f100e51d394a76a158000dc).

It seems like I am unaible to build the gem native extension, and I don't find any workaround.

*Note 1 : I have tried with both 2.3 and 2.3.1.
Note 2 : I have RV.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may be relating to the 'json' native extension compiling. 
If you're on Mac ensure you've Xcode developer kit installed. On Linux, a workaround is to have libgmp3-dev library installed (`sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`) as [indicated in this issue](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253).

For Windows users, [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) is needed.

Comment: I get an error when running `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` : `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.1/.gitignore
`. When I try with sudo : error building gem native extension. See here : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d7a435b10b7388dfd99a28e390dd57af